# If Statement not working properly in Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel

I have a simple If Statement in my controller that is not triggering properly.

I have the following route:

```
Route::resource ('/my-health-hub', 'MyHealthHubController');
```

I have the following in my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $test = Auth::check();

    if ($test = false){

        return redirect('/login');

    } else {
         $providers = $request->user()->providers()->get();
         return view ('my-health-hub', compact('providers'));
    }
}
```

When a user is logged in, the second part of the If Statement is triggered properly.  However, when logged out, the If Statement still tries to trigger the second part of the If Statement.  I did dd($test) to verify the value was false when logged out and it was.  So, the second part of the statement should not be triggering when user is logged out.

Comment: it must be `if($test == false)` not `if($test = false)` with `==` not one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to make a logic comparison you use two assignment operator for compare

in your case you use one assignment operator `=` so it will return true in first case all the time

so all you need to fix it to add `==` instead of `=`

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $test = Auth::check();

    if ($test == false){

        return redirect('/login');

    } else {
         $providers = $request->user()->providers()->get();
         return view ('my-health-hub', compact('providers'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can remove else block completely. It can be written as below (some code optimizations).

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $test = Auth::check();

    if ($test){
        $providers = $request->user()->providers()->get();
        return view ('my-health-hub', compact('providers'));
    }

    return redirect('/login');
}
```